# Ruby hash of hashes, how to get key if there is a key value match into the nested hashes

Tags: ruby, hashmap

I have a ruby hash with this structure:

```ruby
jotform = {
  '1'  => {
    'name'         => 'theGreat',
    'order'        => '1',
    'text'         => 'xxxxx',
    'type'         => 'control_head'
  },
  '3'  => {
    'name'         => 'clickTo',
    'order'        => '2',
    'text'         => '<p>Final date to apply is August 29</p>',
    'type'         => 'control_text'
  },
  '4'  => {
    'name'         => 'personalDetails',
    'order'        => '3',
    'text'         => 'Personal Details',
    'type'         => 'control_head'
  },
  '5'  => {
    'name'         => 'name',
    'order'        => '4',
    'sublabels'    =>
      '{"prefix":"Prefix","first":"First Name","middle":"Middle Name","last":"Last Name","suffix":"Suffix"}',
    'text'         => 'Name',
    'type'         => 'control_fullname',
    'answer'       => {
      'first' => 'Example',
      'last'  => 'Example'
    },
    'prettyFormat' => 'Example'
  },
  '9'  => {
    'name'         => 'country',
    'order'        => '5',
    'text'         => 'Country',
    'type'         => 'control_dropdown',
    'answer'       => 'Germany'
  },
  '10' => {
    'name'         => 'email',
    'order'        => '6',
    'text'         => 'Email',
    'type'         => 'control_email',
    'answer'       => 'picco@example.com'
  },
  '15' => {
    'name'         => 'pageBreak',
    'order'        => '8',
    'text'         => 'Page Break',
    'type'         => 'control_pagebreak'
  },
  '16' => {
    'name'         => 'contributions',
    'order'        => '9',
    'text'         => 'Contributions',
    'type'         => 'control_head'
  }
}
```

This is a payload that I receive from jotform and I have to process in my app.
The issue is that I don't know the field order: this hash has some keys (`'1'`, `'2'`, …) that are equivalent to the form answer.

I must get the name in Pretty Format and the email, so I'm trying to get these values.

Here the email has key `'10'` and the name has key `'5'` but they can change in the next form.

I try with

```ruby
jotform.select { |_key, hash| hash['name'] == 'email' }
```

But it returns

```ruby
{
  '10' => {
    'name'   => 'email',
    'order'  => '6',
    'text'   => 'Email',
    'type'   => 'control_email',
    'answer' => 'example@example.com'
  }
}
```

I need to get the key (`'10'`) if there is a match into this key's value but I cannot understand how.

Comment: _"I must get [...] the email"_ / _"I need to get the key"_ – so do you want the email value `"picco@example.com"` or the key `"10"` or both?

Comment: @Stefan I need the email of course. But if I get the key then is easy to get the email.

Comment: Whoever designed this data structure should have their programming license taken away. Sheesh. Why is `order` a text with a number inside? Why not make it a number? Why is `sublabels` a string with a JSON document inside? Why not a hash? `answer` is a hash, after all, so it is clearly possible. Why are the top-level keys strings with numbers inside instead of numbers? Why are the keys strings instead of symbols? The `type` and `name` values should probably be symbols, too …

Comment: @JörgWMittag: Totally agree. I tried to convert it to a less weird structure https://stackoverflow.com/a/69071984/6419007

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the result of your `select` call:

```
h = jotform.select{ |key, hash| hash["name"] == "email" }
```

You can get the key via:

```
h.keys.first
#=> "10"
```

And the value via:

```
h.values.first["answer"]
#=> "example@example.com"
```

`first` is needed because there could (in theory) be multiple entries for email.

Answer (score 0):

Well, that's a weird format.

I'm not sure I understand it, but assuming that `name` is unique, you could reindex your hash and use `name` as key:

```
new_data = jotform.map do |id, h|
  key = h.delete 'name'
  [key, h.merge('id' => id)]
end.to_h
```

The new format looks like :

```
{"theGreat"=>
  {"order"=>"1", "text"=>"xxxxx", "type"=>"control_head", "id"=>"1"},
 "clickTo"=>
  {"order"=>"2",
   "text"=>"<p>Final date to apply is August 29</p>",
   "type"=>"control_text",
   "id"=>"3"},
 "personalDetails"=>
  {"order"=>"3",
   "text"=>"Personal Details",
   "type"=>"control_head",
   "id"=>"4"},
 "name"=>
  {"order"=>"4",
   "sublabels"=>
    "{\"prefix\":\"Prefix\",\"first\":\"First Name\",\"middle\":\"Middle Name\",\"last\":\"Last Name\",\"suffix\":\"Suffix\"}",
   "text"=>"Name",
   "type"=>"control_fullname",
   "answer"=>{"first"=>"Example", "last"=>"Example"},
   "prettyFormat"=>"Example",
   "id"=>"5"},
 "country"=>
  {"order"=>"5",
   "text"=>"Country",
   "type"=>"control_dropdown",
   "answer"=>"Germany",
   "id"=>"9"},
 "email"=>
  {"order"=>"6",
   "text"=>"Email",
   "type"=>"control_email",
   "answer"=>"picco@example.com",
   "id"=>"10"},
 "pageBreak"=>
  {"order"=>"8",
   "text"=>"Page Break",
   "type"=>"control_pagebreak",
   "id"=>"15"},
 "contributions"=>
  {"order"=>"9", "text"=>"Contributions", "type"=>"control_head", "id"=>"16"}}
```

No information has been lost, and it should be easier to access. In order to get the email address, you can simply use:

```
new_data["email"]["answer"]
#=> "picco@example.com"
```